# Uploading same image file in formset returns ValueError

Tags: django, django-forms

I've been working with django 1.4 in doing a formset whereby users can use to upload one or more images.

The formset is used in a wizard step but manually am handling the is_valid check and formset.save() at the done method.

The formset is behaving very weird, when I choose different images in the formset it works perfectly. But, when I upload the same image in two fields I get the following error

```
ValueError at /item/post-project/

I/O operation on closed file
```

it is very weird and am not sure how to debug such a problem, I tried to use a function to replace the upload_to parameter in the file field to always use uuid fields incase it was throwing this error because of file naming duplication, but it did not solve the problem.

here is my function

```
AttachmentFormSet   = inlineformset_factory(Item, Attachment, extra=attachment_form_extra, max_num=8, can_delete=False, form=AttachmentForm)
formset = AttachmentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance,)
if formset.is_valid():
  formset.save()
```

any advise on how to solve this issue?

Error Stack

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/post-project/

Django Version: 1.4.3
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('admin_tools',
 'admin_tools.theming',
 'admin_tools.menu',
 'admin_tools.dashboard',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'social_auth',
 'account',
 'item',
 'sponsor',
 'pages',
 'misc.helper')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/yrok/yrok/apps/item/views.py" in post_item
  105.     return response(request)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in dispatch
  223.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/yrok/yrok/apps/item/wizards.py" in post
  109.                 return self.render_done(form, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in render_done
  328.         done_response = self.done(final_form_list, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/yrok/yrok/apps/item/wizards.py" in done
  156.         formset.save()
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  497.         return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_new_objects
  628.             self.new_objects.append(self.save_new(form, commit=commit))
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_new
  731.             obj.save()
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/yrok/yrok/apps/item/models.py" in save
  327.         super(Attachment, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1593.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  911.         for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  872.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  249.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  86.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  45.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in _save
  195.                         for chunk in content.chunks():
File "/Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/yrok-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py" in chunks
  63.             self.seek(0)

Exception Type: ValueError at /item/post-project/
Exception Value: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: Entire error traceback would be helpful.

Comment: What's the form look like? Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029988/django-gives-i-o-operation-on-closed-file-error-when-reading-from-a-saved-imag help?

Comment: Or does the overridden `Attachment.save` do something before invoking `super(...)`?